# Decrypting KMS CipherText blob to plain text in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, encryption, aws-sdk, amazon-kms

Trying to use AWS KMS Client to decrypt cipher text from a java application. I can get the plaintext value using the command line with this command

```
aws kms decrypt --ciphertext-blob fileb://<(echo "AQICAHhQoQKI7DHhSjurtJ5l16Ti5tLXuHgI7e1RBO+bzfXslgH+QBBjbCbdtHDmILDAXZ5MAAAAZTBjBgkqhkiG9w0BBwagVjBUAgEAME8GCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMJ/bb9e0MrMYZ3CVrAgEQgCKMSh5cGRzlZeADspZArSYDlVABnxjye7TSDvRnfBikkZGe" | base64 -D) --output text --query Plaintext --region eu-west-1 | base64
```

Here is my java code, which gives me back some slightly less hashed value

```
        final String encryptedCipherText = "AQICAHhQoQKI7DHhSjurtJ5l16Ti5tLXuHgI7e1RBO+bzfXslgH+QBBjbCbdtHDmILDAXZ5MAAAAZTBjBgkqhkiG9w0BBwagVjBUAgEAME8GCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMJ/bb9e0MrMYZ3CVrAgEQgCKMSh5cGRzlZeADspZArSYDlVABnxjye7TSDvRnfBikkZGe";

        AWSKMS kmsClient;

        kmsClient = AWSKMSClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withRegion("eu-west-1")
                .build();

        ByteBuffer cipherTextBlob = ByteBuffer.wrap(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedCipherText));
        DecryptRequest decryptRequest = new DecryptRequest().withCiphertextBlob(cipherTextBlob);
        ByteBuffer key = kmsClient.decrypt(decryptRequest).getPlaintext();
        final byte[] bytes = new byte[key.remaining()];
        key.duplicate().get(bytes);
        String result = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
        System.out.println("decrypted plaintext value: " + result);
```

NOTE - if I remove `base64 -D` from the AWS CLI command I mentioned above I get the same value that my java decrypt function returns..

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get the value with this code

```
    AWSKMS kmsClient;

    kmsClient = AWSKMSClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withRegion("eu-west-1")
            .build();


    ByteBuffer cipherTextBlob = ByteBuffer.wrap(Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherTextBlob));

    DecryptRequest req = new DecryptRequest().withCiphertextBlob(cipherTextBlob);
    ByteBuffer plainText = kmsClient.decrypt(req).getPlaintext();

    return new String(plainText.array());
```